# Setting default in entity model for Type Time

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, time

I've tried a few values but nothing works.  I could randomly try values (I did a few) and try searching (yep nothing after about 30 minutes of looking) or ask the SO folks.

So trying to set the default Time to 5:30:00 PM (17:30:00) when I create a new record.  I thought all I needed to do was set it in the properties, and it seems correct, but doesn't like the value I put in.  17:00:00.0000000 and 17:00:00 and 17:00:00.0 all failed.

See image [image: Notice on the right the default and left the error message]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your time to:

> 17:30:00.0000000z

Comment: Error 6039: Invalid Primitive Type: System.TimeSpan. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.()

Answer (score 0):

```
17:30:00.0000000Z
```

That works for me with a database column having type Time(7).  Mark Oreta's also worked.  I received the same error when I omited the z or Z.  Is there an issue in your table mappings?

Comment: Tried Z and z.  Both failed with the same Error 6039: Invalid Primitive Type: System.TimeSpan. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.()